# Help! I need to finish my movie!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography, imgur-maze

I need help!

> I was watching a movie with my friend, when suddenly it cut off right at the climax, and gave me this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obh71.png

It looks like that links to a puzzle hunt. Please please please help me solve this, I really want to know how it all ends. :(

(P.S. This is my first puzzle, suggestions would be nice.)

> Important!
>   
>   There are TWO errors on puzzle #7, 
>   1) the arrows are supposed to be reversed. There is no trick 
>   2) the right side should say +0 +11 -1 +1 (in the original, there is no text)

Hints: (*=revealing)

HINT 0 (General)

> Check capital i vs lowercase L

HINT 1 (*) (puzzle #3)

> Check the tags

HINT 2 (*) (puzzle #4)

> I hope you play an instrument

Hint 3 (puzzle #6)

> What do you think the first line says?

Hint 4 (puzzle #9)

> Oops! Bad grammar

Hint 5 (puzzle #11)

> Something is fishy about character count...

Hint 6 (puzzle #11)

> How can I combine the strings?

Hint 7 (puzzle #12)

> I am trying to get a string of 5 letters. What can I do?

Hint 8 (*) (final puzzle)

> Look at puzzle #13 more closely...

Comment: Very minor spoiler: rot13(uggcf://v.cnfgr.cvpf/49Q81.cat) 
I should not find that funny.

Comment: Minor error on the first image, which should not have affected anyone currently solving. I have changed it.

Comment: Added hints for anyone stuck. Try not to use them :)

Comment: Are you aware the cryptic clues tag not just for ambiguous clues but follow a very specific set of rules to what defines a cryptic clue? I didn't see anything that falls under the category but wasn't sure if I just hadn't made it far enough. If you read the tag descriptions you can get some more info if you'd like. Also is there a reason you chose to have the puzzle link out instead of adding the image into the question?

Comment: No there is no reason why I decided to omit the image. Also, thanks for clarifying the tag. I was unaware of what it meant, and I will remove it.

Comment: ERROR ON PUZZLE #7: THE ARROWS ARE SUPPOSED TO BE REVERSED. THERE IS NO TRICK

Comment: just confirming so that that Im not jumping down a rabbit hole,  is uggcf://v.fgnpx.vzthe.pbz/yvmxn.cat (ROT13) a part of the solution ? (Im unsure as uggcf://v.fgnpx.vzthe.pbz/YVMXn.cat (ROT13) does not lead to anything) or is it just an unlucky coincidence

Comment: The second link is nearly correct. rot13(Pncvgny v if ybjrepnfr Y vf naablvat)

Answer (score 9):

**Partial solution (puzzles 1-5)**

First puzzle:

> The signature is the link to the next puzzle: [LlZKa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlZKa.png)

Second puzzle:

> The "13" next to `mByIb` refers to rot13. The answer is [zOlVo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOlVo.png).

Third puzzle:

> Taking the last bits of each of the RGB channels of the first row of the picture and combining them in the order "RGBRGB..." gives the string [WZb2J](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZb2J.png)

Fourth puzzle:

> DRMF_LTD = Do Re Mi Fa **Sol** La Ti Do. It seems like we have to complete the song that starts with "mi re do re mi" and play the next five keys on the "piano" below (moving your hand down after every note). The song is "Mary had a Little Lamb" and the next five notes are "mi mi re re re", which makes [YdzpA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdzpA.png)

Fifth puzzle:

> Moving on the keyboard in direction of the arrows from each of the letters and pressing them gives: `dripK0tIz`. The link to the next puzzle is: [K0tIz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0tIz.png)

Sixth puzzle:

> Can't figure it out... Maybe it has something to do with "drip" from the previous puzzle?

Comment: Very good progress! I have a hint for the sixth puzzle in the OP if you need it. As a slight nitpick, I was looking for "so" instead of "sol"

Comment: For puzzle #3, rot13(ubj qvq lbh pbapyhqr gung lbh arrqrq gb purpx gur ETO punaaryf bs gur svefg ebj?)

Comment: @NigelMNZ rot13(Gur ynfg ovg bs nyy punaaryf vf 0 rkprcg sbe gur svefg srj cvkryf va gur vzntr. Ernqvat gur ynfg ovg bs gur cvkryf va beqre tvirf gur nafjre.)

Comment: Giving you the bounty so it doesn't go to waste. Will add another one as soon as I have enough reputation

Comment: Using rot13(EBG guvegrra) seems to give something slightly more intelligible…

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Solution**

Puzzles 1-5:

> See answers by @Stefan.

Puzzle 6:

> The message is encoded with a Vigenere cipher. By guessing that "Wvh yhm" means "The key", you can find the cipher key, "do". 
>  
>  
> Decoding the full message gives you: "The key: do FZ2ag". This leads to [FZ2ag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ2ag.png).

Puzzle 7:

> No clue. Even with the correction it sort of just feels like I'm missing some fundamental axiom of the puzzle.

Comment: Just a slight note, the key is rot13(qb abg qbqb)

Comment: Hint: rot13(Qb lbh haqrefgnaq "+"? Jul jbhyq -9 or haqrsvarq)

Comment: rot13(Tvira gurer ner bayl gjb fhz pyhrf gb jbex jvgu, zl orfg thrff vf gung fhzzngvba vf whfg zbqhyne nqqvgvba. (zbq 12) Nf sbe fhogenpgvba, gur gjb rknzcyrf qba'g yrnir zr jvgu zhpu. V thrffrq gung artngvir ahzoref whfg jenc onpx sbejneq fxvccvat 0, fb 4 fho 7 pbhyq or 4. Ubjrire, gur A/N rdhngvba fgvyy fghzcf. Bar cbffvoyr vqrn jnf gung ahzoref jrer va onfr-9, ohg gung jbhyq oernx gur ynfg rdhngvba. Gura gurer'f fgvyy gur znggre bs ubj gb hfr gur ahzoref, fvapr nccneragyl obgu gur ubhe naq zvahgr unaq ner eryrinag.)

Comment: 7-3=N/A, 3-1=3. Does this help?